# Fastest way to get data from server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, ios4

I have a DB and web server in the same host. I have an iPhone app that sends XML to the web server. The web server will query the database and return data back to the app.

I'm not sure whether this is the fastest way

Are there other ways faster than this?

Comment: Yes, do it in a background thread.

Comment: Threads don't speed up network queries, they just let you distract the user while the query is taking place.

Comment: Have you tried JSON? What are you using for the backend?

Comment: @Caleb: You're right, but making slow things *feel* faster than they are is a fundamental skill in user-interface design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server-client programs, the biggest bottleneck is usually the network latency unless you are doing very complicated time-consuming processing at server side or you have behemoth data in your RDBMS and need to search from it.

There are a couple of things (scopes more than XML) that you may try for fast loading:

1. If you are feeling that database is the bottleneck, you may try caching (look for [MemcacheD](http://memcached.org/) and the likes) objects in front of database. This will reduce DB hits and retrieval will be faster.
2. Use compression in XML. Or use shorter notation like JSON or YAML. 
    *In general, for webapps*:
3. Reuse and use optimized (compressed) images. Use more CSS less images wherever you can.
4. Minify the components like CSS and JS.
5. Don't load everything at once, if not needed.

You may look into [XML compressors](http://www.packetizer.com/xml/xml_compression.html) or if you can, use some shorter notation like [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). But I guess it will be hard to change data format if you have already developed the app.

Answer (score 1):

XML isn't the world's most compact format, so you could obviously speed things up by reducing the amount of data that you send and receive. If you can talk to the database directly, you can cut out the web server, which would surely speed things up too.

The thing is, though, that XML and HTTP are standards, and there's a lot of value in that. Is the small increase in speed that you get from a purpose-built custom protocol really worth the loss of flexibility and extra development time?

Comment: +1 Agreed. HTTP is fine for almost anything where the data chunks aren't giant.